# npm: Replacing one package from dependencies with a fork (possibly using git)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm using [terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser), which requires [esprima](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima). Esprima has been abandoned, so I'd like to replace it with the fork [esprima-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima-next). However, no method which I've used to do this has been successful.

**Attempt 1:**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "esprima": "npm:esprima-next"
},
```

This installs without error, but the contents in `node_modules/esprima` are unchanged.

**Attempt 2:**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "esprima": "github:node-projects/esprima-next"
},
```

This results in the following:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/node-projects/esprima-next.git
npm ERR! ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new: line 1: ssh: not found
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "esprima": "git+https://github.com/node-projects/esprima-next.git"
},
```

This results in the same error as the second attempt.

How can I replace one dependency with a fork?

**Update 1:**

I found that I can install `esprima-next` under the `esprima` name and directory by pointing to the tarball for `esprima-next`.

```
npm show esprima-next

... get the tarball URL from the output

npm install --save esprima@https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima-next/-/esprima-next-5.8.1.tgz
```

This works, in that `node_modules/esprima/` contains the right code. However, packages like `requirejs` and `terser` seem to bundle `esprima` in their own code, and so I still can't get them to use `esprima-next`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `resolutions` in your `package.json`.

```
devDependencies: {
  terser: ^5.0.0,
  ....
},
resolutions: {
   "esprima": "git+https://github.com/node-projects/esprima-next.git"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using?